# ¿Cómo hacer commit o rollback al confirmar o cancelar datos en Laravel? (POO)

Tags: php, laravel, poo, laravel-8

Tengo una tabla html donde se puede interactuar con datos (editar, añadir y eliminar) Y a último momento me dijeron que esos datos no deben guardarse hasta que se dé a "confirmar". Además, en caso de darle a "cancelar" se debe restablecer todo.

Primero, se me ocurrió crear una tabla "clon" de la real, de tal forma que, al editar, eliminar y añadir se haga sobre ese clon. Para no extenderme mucho, les comento que no me parece una solución idónea.

Ahora estoy intentando trabajar con transacciones pero no me funciona (tampoco sé cómo hacerlo).

La idea más o menos es la siguiente:

```php
 private $tr;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
            $this->tr = DB::beginTransaction();
        }
        
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
        //Aquí se obtienen datos con DB::Select 
        }
        public function update(Request $request){
        //Aquí se actualizan datos con DB::Table
        }
        public function destroy(Request $request)
        {
        //Aquí se eliminan datos con DB::Delete
        }
        
        public function apply(Request $request)
        {
        //Aquí cuando se le da a "confirmar"
        $this->tr->commit(); //Creo que tengo que hacer algo así
        return response()->json(['success'=>true], 202);
        }
        
        public function cancel(Request $request){
        //Aquí cuando se le da a "cancelar"
        $this->tr->rollback(); //Supongo que tengo que hacer algo así
        return response()->json(['success'=>true], 202);
    
    }
```

Comment: En mi opinión, la opción mas sencilla es que los campos de tu tabla los pongas en un <input>, los cuales puedas modificar, o una solución alternativa. De esta manera luego podrás recoger los valores cuando envíes el formulario con tu botón de enviar, y si lo cancelas, como no has guardado nada, cuando vuelvas a entrar tendrá los valores de tu base de datos

Comment: Coincido con la respuesta de arriba. El objetivo de las transacciones es que los datos sean íntegros, es decir, que si hay que actualizar 100 registros sean todos o ninguno. No son para guardar datos temporalmente, hacer eso podría traer más problemas.